# javafx.scene.media.MediaView cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Parent

Tags: java, video, javafx, media

I have a `MediaView` and I want to play a fullscreen video ..  i just can't find the right parent to my `MediaView` .. it gives me this error 
`javafx.scene.media.MediaView cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Parent`

that's my fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<MediaView fx:id="astrolabe_intro" fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="astrolabe.astrolabe_introController" />
```

and that's my controller

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class astrolabe_introController implements Initializable {

    String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File video = new File(workingDir, "src/astrolabe/img/astrolab_movie.mp4");
    Media m = new Media(video.toURI().toString());
    MediaPlayer astrolabe_intro = new MediaPlayer(m);


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        astrolabe_intro.play();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not use [`MediaView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaView.html) as the root node, because it doesn't extend from [`Parent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html). Try to wrap your `MediaView` inside a [`Pane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html). For example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="astrolabe.astrolabe_introController" >
    <MediaView fx:id="astrolabe_intro"/>
</AnchorPane>
```

**N.B.** *You might also want to define different reference name for your `MediaView` and `MediaPlayer`. In the above example you have defined `fx:id` of `MediaView` and ref for `MediaPlayer` as `astrolabe_intro`*

A simple example of [MediaView/MediaPlayer is here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaView.html) and [FXML is here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm)

Comment: i thought that giving both the same id will link the media player to media view like saying " play that media on this view " .. is that wrong ?

Comment: Yes that is completely incorrect, you must start learning about how fxml works, start with the examples. I have provided a link, going through it will give you a better idea.